# How can you conduct a simple test for a MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet

Is there a simple way of conducting a test on a MOSFET? For example, testing if a transistor is in good condition or not by using a multimeter. Can the same test work for a MOSFET?

Comment: Are we talking about **only** a multimeter and a MOSFET or are we talking about a very simple circuit (max 3 components) + a multimeter and a MOSFET?

Comment: Yes, only a multimeter and a MOSFET.

Comment: I think you will have some difficulties, because a multimeter is a 2-terminal device, and a MOSFET is a 3-terminal device. Imagine a 3D-model being squished into 2D, it's not a perfect metaphor, but you are removing **very much** information. It's a very safe bet that you are also removing the possibility of seeing whether or not a MOSFET is good or not, depending on some random criteria. - Good luck.

Comment: I see, I'll have a look at any alternative ways of testing a MOSFET. Thanks!

Comment: You could... change your question to include a minimalistic circuit. Or just get a [cheap multimeter](https://youtu.be/7Br3L1B80ow?t=215). Notice how all 3 terminals are being connected in the link, and then measured internally of the multimeter in some simple circuit. Not 2, but 3. - I want to correct my earlier metaphor, I said 3D-model => 2D. It's actually more like 3D-model => 1D, because the current is the same at the 2-terminals. Again, this is just a metaphor. Trying to make you understand that you are throwing away an absurd amount of information trying to only do it with 2 terminals.

Answer (score 3):

About the only thing you can test with a mulitmeter is the gross state of the gate. Measuring from the gate to the source should give you essentially open circuit. Actually, it will look like a capacitor in the 1000 pf to 10000 pf range. If it looks like a low-value resistor you know that the gate is blown and you can discard the FET.

To test anything else you need a circuit, but that circuit can be very simple. For instance, a decent overall tester might be

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBvBpb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the switch is open the LED should be off, and when the switch is closed the LED should be on. Almost any LED will work (although you should avoid IR LEDs - they are a bit hard to see). To be safe, 12 volts is better than 5. Some FETs won't work well in this circuit with only 5 volts on the gate, but many will do OK.

This circuit will test the basic functionality of most n-type FETs in switch mode, which is the most common use these days. It is not appropriate for RF FETS, but I doubt you're interested - if you are doing RF amps with only a multimeter as instrumentation you're doomed anyways.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I suppose by building a simple circuit it does provide a good basis to work off.

Answer (score 3):

TL/DR: Multimeter in diode mode, FET not in circuit, probe across each pair of pins with both polarities, so you probe 6 times, you should get 1 diode threshold and 5 opens. If you get something that looks like a short, dead FET.

Power MOSFETs usually fail shorted, which means if the FET was used in a topology like H-bridge or DC-DC synchronous buck the MOSFETs most likely shorted the supply rails and had a quite large supply rail capacitor discharge through them. Thus the first test is to visually check for holes, cracks, or bits missing from the MOSFET. If it's a synchronous buck or H-bridge, also check the other FET. If one shorts, both usually pop.

Then, if it is a MOSFET with a body diode, the usual test is to probe in diode mode until you get a realistic diode threshold value like 0.6V. This lets you know which pins are drain and source. If it's a common package and you assume it has the usual pinout, then you can guess if it's a P or NMOS by which way the body diode goes.

If the diode is between gate and another pin, then it's a JFET, not a MOSFET.

Then reverse polarity and check you get an open across the body diode.

Then check the gate is not shorted to the source.

If it's a SO-8 or similar package it may contain more than one FET, so watch out for this.

If it's a TO-220 or larger thru-hole inside the output stage of an audio amp or other linear power stage, it may be a Lateral MOSFET, in this case the source is the center pin (and the tab). Much more common Vertical FETs have the drain in the center (and tab).

That's about all the tests you'd do to know if it's busted or not. For characteristics, just read the datasheet.

If you want to test it without desoldering it, some awareness of the surrounding circuit will be required. Probe longer to allow capacitors to charge. But if you get something like 0.1 ohms between any two pins... time to desolder it.

If you still want to really check if it works or not, you can apply a voltage on the gate, using a bench power supply or a battery and a potentiometer... connect the other channel of the supply across drain and source and set to a low current limit like a few mA, or use a battery-LED-resistor, and you'll be able to make the FET switch and get a rough measurement of its threshold voltage.

Note that if you're interested in measuring VgsTH for example, you must use a tiny current, as any sort of current that is large enough to heat the FET will of course change VgsTH. For this kind of stuff, a proper curve tracer is required.

Comment: This is the type of tests I was considering, this definitely clarifies things. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use your fingers as a variable-resistance, you can do this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkdwat.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Oh, come on. Can't you at least show a MOSFET?